# Questions about delete a row with double quotes and prepared statement in SQL

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, sql-delete, double-quotes

I try to delete a row in SQL with the same `bookID` and `userID`, but because my `bookID` saved with a double-quote, normal delete won't match. What should I do? Thanks.

```
String deleteString = "DELETE FROM booksFavourite WHERE userID=? AND bookID=?;";

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("someLink");
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(deleteString);
        ps.setInt(1, userID);
        ps.setString(2, bookID);
        int r = ps.executeUpdate();
    }//try
```

...

[here is my sql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gdxS.jpg)

Comment: Tip: The `;` delimiter is used by interactive shells to separate statements. It is not necessary or recommended to use within program code where each statement is supplied to the driver.

Comment: @tadman why not recommended?

Comment: @Strawberry It's just clutter and it suggests you're not entirely confident about what you're supposed to be doing, or in the worst case an artifact of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) so a point of concern as well. Queries must be very precisely composed, so attention to detail here is key. A single missing character can utterly destroy a production database. Keep it clean and it looks like you're paying attention and are concerned about details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trim your `bookID` so it will match on your parameter.

```
 String deleteString = "DELETE FROM booksFavourite WHERE userID=? AND trim(both '\"' from bookID)=?;";
```

**or**

You can `concat` `"` on your parameter to match on your bookID

```
   String deleteString = "DELETE FROM booksFavourite WHERE userID=? AND bookID=concat('\"', ?, '\"');";
```

Comment: Since this query has both quotes involved it needs more escaping or it's not valid syntax.